Can't decide between resource or route based invokation
Due to immense noob'ity regarding Python in general and Flask in particular, I'm fundamentally confused regarding the conventions, best practices and common know-how. I try to follow the examples provided by Microsoft (as we're working with Azure) and I start to suspect they might be... Microsoft'ish (i.e. "it works but...").
Based on various examples, I've created two endpoints, carrying the same computation, resulting in equivalent payloads (not the same structure, though!) and I can't figure out which is the recommended approach. One is using resourcing (coupled with a route), while the other is explicitly routing.
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, request
from logic import compute

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class computer (Resource):
    def get(self):
        return compute(request.args.to_dict())

api.add_resource(computer, "/compute-resource")

@app.route("/compute-route", methods=["GET"])
def execute():
    return compute(request.args.to_dict())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

The only (weirdly unexpected) I noticed in the output is that the latter seems to sort the fields of returned JSON alphabetically while the first one doesn't it.

Which of those two approaches is preferred or are they equivalently appropriate?
What is the deviation in field ordering suggesting if anything?

